# How to update .htaccess file for another folder along side wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I have a wordpress site with complete URL as:

```
mydomain.com/wp_myfolder/index.php
```

but after WordPress rewriting I access my site as `mydomain.com` Now I want to place another project in another folder on same domain but I am facing issues

I want to access my new project as this but it is not working

```
mydomain.com/project/mypage.php
```

instead it is opening as

```
mydomain.com/wp_myfolder/project/mypage.php
```

it want to remove **wp_myfolder** from url

Comment: You have to change the URL of your site in the Wordpress back office, or in the wp_param table, I don't remember exactly.

Comment: I updated 2 values in wordpress-> settings 1. WordPress Address (URL) and 2. site Address (URL). Also I updated 1 php file manually

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this rewrite rule in your .htaccess.

```
RewriteRule    ^project/(.*)$    /wp_myfolder/project/$1    [L]
```

Comment: not working , it says Whoah! 404 error! We can't find the page!